# is it possible to have reqrep for each server in haproxy loadbalancer?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

There are 3 servers in a load balanced HAProxy setup.

```
 server      serv1 192.168.1.101:8080 check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 1
 server      serv2 192.168.1.102:8080 check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 1

#The legacy Apache server will listen on port 81 and perform URL rewriting/load balancing
 server      serv_legacy 192.168.1.110:81 check inter 2000 rise 1 fall 1
```

However, one of the 3 servers (serv_legacy) respond to a different url request. I was wondering if it is possible to have reqrep url redirection for the third server only.